# email sent successfully but no email received and not in spam using swiftmailer

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I am using Swiftmailer. Though mail is received in local successfully but it doesn't work in live though message is 'mail sent successfully'.
Code:

```
require_once APPPATH.'swiftmailer/swift_required.php';

        try {
            $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
            // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
            $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

            // Create a message
            $message = Swift_Message::newInstance($email_subject)
                ->setFrom(array('xxx@yyy.org' => 'xxx'))
                ->setTo(array('abc@gmail.com' => ''))
                ->setBody($email_message, 'text/html');

            // Send the message
            $result = $mailer->send($message);
            $message = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => 'Email Sent successfully.');

        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo '<pre>'; echo $e; die;
            $message = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $e);
       }
```

Any help/suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Email sent successfully shows because the the functionality of the php is to deliver the mail to the mail server running as per your configuration in your php.ini file. It is the job of the mail server to send mail or not. If your mail server is not configured properly then mail will not be sent but it will be shown as successful because mail function delivered the mail to the server, now it is the job of mail server to send mail or not. So check the log of your mail server.